# Direct-inclusion sorting

Tags: c++

What is the other name for direct-inclusion sorting and what is the algorithm for the same sort?

I have been trying to search on the Internet, but I'm not getting a straight answer, but I can not find any. I found this algorithm for straight insertion sort and in some books it's saying they are the same with direct direct-inclusion sorting, but I'm doubting it because the book is in Russian, so I want to confirm (that is, if it's true or might I have a translation error?)

Code in C++:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[8] = {27, 412, 71, 81, 59, 14, 273, 87},i,j;

    for (j=1; j<8; j++){
        if (arr[j] < arr[j-1]) {
            //Что бы значение j мы не меняли а работали с i
            i = j;
            //Меняем местами пока не найдем нужное место
            do{
                swap(arr[i],arr[i-1]);
                i--;
                //защита от выхода за пределы массива
                if (i == 0)
                    break;
            }
            while (arr[i] < arr[i-1]) ;
        }
        for (i=0;i<8;i++)
            cout << arr[i]<< ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

#### Result

```
27 412 71 81 59 14 273 87
27 71 412 81 59 14 273 87
27 71 81 412 59 14 273 87
27 59 71 81 412 14 273 87
14 27 59 71 81 412 273 87
14 27 59 71 81 273 412 87
14 27 59 71 81 87 273 412
```

Answer (score 2):

The posted code is [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Most implementations will copy an out-of-order element to a temporary variable and then work backwards, moving elements up until the correct open spot is found to "insert" the current element. That's what the pseudocode in the Wikipedia article shows.

Some implementations just bubble the out-of-order element backwards while it's less than the element to its left. That's what the inner `do...while` loop in the posted code shows.

Both methods are valid ways to implement Insertion sort.

Comment: Indeed it appears so. It demonstrates every property, and Wiki is definitely NOT wrong as someone claimed. This will degenerate to O(n^2) in worst-case, O(n) in best case. Thanks for the link, sir. It reminded me how much I need to crack my Sedgewick books on a more-regular basis =P.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted looks not like an algorithm for insertion sort, since you are doing a repeated swap of two neighboring elements.

Your code looks much more like some kind of bubble-sort.

Here a list of common sorting algorithms:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

"straight insertion" and "direct inclusion" sounds like pretty much the same .. so I quess they probably are different names for the same algorithm.

Edit:
Possibly the "straight" prefix should indicate that only one container is used .. however, if two neighboring elements are swaped, I would not call it insertion-sort, since no "insert" is done at all.

Comment: Your first paragraph isn't correct. [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is in-place and doesn't require two containers. There is also nothing special about a swap operation that prevents it from being Insertion sort.

Comment: Than I dont see where the difference to a Bubble-Sort is. If you are right, wikipedia is wrong  (However would not be the first time)

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the term "direct inclusion sort" yields no google hits at all, and "direct insertion sorting" only 27 hits, the first three of which are this post here and two identically phrased [blog](http://jisku.com/blog/2012/09/direct-inclusion-sorting/) [posts](http://umeedaintimes.com/direct-inclusion-sorting/), I doubt that this term has any widely accepted meaning. So the part of your question about

> some book its saying they are the same with direct direct-inclusion sorting

is hard to answer, unless we find a clear definition of what *direct-inclusion sorting* actually is.